# Service not injected in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to inject the following service to a component:

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ColorService {       
  private colorPalettes = [

        [
            'rgba(36, 123, 160, 1)',
            'rgba(112, 193, 179, 1)',
            'rgba(178, 219, 191, 1)',
            'rgba(243, 255, 189, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 22, 84, 1)'
        ]
  ]
  constructor() { // some calculations
  }
}
```

And then I inject it as follows:

```
import { Component , Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ColorService } from '../colors.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'search-form',
  templateUrl: 'search-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'search-form.component.css']
})

export class SearchFormComponent {
    @Input() colors : ColorService;

    onTagsAdded(tag) {
        console.log(this.colors);
    }
}
```

However this.colors is undefined. I also set ColorService as a provider in app.module in order to inject it.

Comment: Have you specified it as a provider in your app.module?? and you need to inject it with your class's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

To use service in component you have to do as folows :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ColorService } from '../colors.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'search-form',
  templateUrl: 'search-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ 'search-form.component.css']
})

export class SearchFormComponent {

    constructor(private colors: ColorService ) {
        console.log(this.colors);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @ranakrunal9's answer, make sure to mark it as a provider in the module that uses it (for example, your app module):

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import './rxjs-operators';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { NavModule } from './shared/nav/nav.module';
import { ThisService } from './shared/this.service';
import { ThatService } from './shared/that.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, NavModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [ ThisService, ThatService ] // this is the important part
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `search-form` element should have a attribute `colors` (because of `@Input()`) where you define the ColorService.

```
<search-form [color]="myColorService" />
```

and in the component where the view is associated you should also inject ColorService and define `myColorService` in the constructor

```
constructor(private myColorService: ColorService) {
}
```

Hope this helps.